# click() working perfectly in firefox and chrome but strange behavior in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have some interesting behavior that I am stuck on

I've got a vb.net page that allows the user to add and remove items from a form dynamically, the Add and Remove functions are both using jQuery on the front end

```
function remRow(clicked_id) {
    console.log("Start remRow");
    $("#hdnID").val(clicked_id);
    document.getElementById("remrow").click();
    console.log("End remRow");
}
```

This clicks a hidden button within an update panel who's event handler in the code behind removes the selected row from array of HtmlGenericControl. The reason for the extra step of the jQuery is the list of possible form elements they can add comes through ajax on the front end, but the HtmlGenericControl is on the back end.

The remRow function is attached to a dynamically created button as part of the array of HtmlGenericControl

On Chrome and Firefox the form element is removed immediately as needed, on IE a single click will show in console as

```
Start remRow
End remRow
```

and the row will not be removed, a double click will show

```
Start remRow
End remRow
Start remRow
End remRow
ROW REMOVED!
```

and while the row has been removed from the array of HtmlGenericControl it still remains on the screen until a third single click.
My addRow function is identical to the remRow function and works fine every time in all browsers, its only the removing row function with this behavior

I've tried several different ideas, such as wrapping the function contents in a

```
$('document').ready(function(){});
```

and using other methods of clicking the button such as

```
$("#remRow").click()
```

I'm not sure why code working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox is failing on IE

edit: 
@BojanIvanac remrow is a button within the update panel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="formPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

    <!-- Hidden Elements -->
    <asp:Button ID="remrow" style="display:none;" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="addrow" style="display:none;" runat="server"/>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind:

```
Private Sub btnremrow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles remrow.Click
    RemoveRow() // Gets called on double click, does not update UpdatePanel
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you build a [mcve]?

Comment: is "remrow" a div? Div's don't have a click event they handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, it turned out to be a bit of strange case.

The document.getElementById("remrow").click(); was firing, but because I had both an ASP button being generated dynamically calling the remRow() function, and then another ASP button being clicked by that function both within the same update panel, a postback was being fired but then being interrupted by the second buttons postback. I'm not sure why the issue only came up in IE.

I fixed it by modifying both of the buttons to be HTML buttons instead of an ASP buttons, and calling the server side handler that removes the row from the static html button

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="always">
  <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="FormItemsHere" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

      <asp:Button ID="addrow" style="display:none;" runat="server"/>
      <!-- Modified Button -->
      <button id="remrow" type="button" runat="server" style="display:none;" onserverclick="btnremrow_Click"></button> 

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and for the dynamically generated button:

```
Dim btnRem As New HtmlButton() With {
    .ID = "btnRem" + Convert.ToString(rowcount),
    .InnerText = "Remove"
}
btnRem.Attributes.Add("onClick", "remRow('" + Convert.ToString(rowcount) + "')")
```

instead of:

```
Dim btnRem As New Button() With {
    .ID = "btnRem" + Convert.ToString(rowcount),
    .Text = "Remove",
    .OnClientClick = "remRow('" + Convert.ToString(rowcount) + "')"
}
```

I also cleared the list of HtmlControl at the end of the btnremrow_Click and remade it for good measure

```
    FormItemsHere.Controls.Clear()
    For Each control As Control In row
        FormItemsHere.Controls.Add(control)
    Next
```

Hope that helps anyone else who comes across the same problem

Answer (score 0):

To click a button, you should call the trigger function:

```
$("#remRow").trigger( "click" );
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: This has the same problem, I believe the issue is more likely to be something to do with the update panel than the jquery syntax